# Static files fully from cache?

Tags: browser-cache, static-files

Check this picture: http://i54.tinypic.com/2gy7mrt.png

How to achieve that for my static files? I mean so the browser even wouldn't make a request to server, just take the file from cache.
On what static files should this method be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your server is Apache, have a look at [mod_expire](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html).

The static files I have configured to expire "later" are `text/css`, `text/javascript`, `application/javascript` and `image/*`.

Comment: It's nginx. Any tips on that? Or I should switch to Apache?

Comment: Surely you have your reasons for using nginx. I will not try to convince you to use something else just so my answer is right. However you might want to check out [HttpHeadersModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) for nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Send `304 Not Modified` header.

I would use it on anything that is unlikely to change often - your site's logo, sprite image, etc.

If you have sent far distant expiry headers, and then decided you need to change the asset, simply append a time stamp / release, e.g. `sprites.png?4000`.